# Do I need transit visa in Moscow while travelling from Guangzhou, CN to Vienna - VIE]

Tags: transit-visas

I am an Indian Passport holder. I do not want to leave SVO, Moscow airport. Do I still need transit visa for travelling from Guangzhou, CN to Vienna - VIE? Will 3 hours  be enough to pass through all immigration and others issues?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to leave the airport, and you your connection is shorter than 24 hours, you don't need a transit visa. When arriving in Sheremetevo, you should be in possession of the ticket for the next flight leg, with confirmed seating. (Acc to http://www.svo.aero/transit/int-int/.)